Can objective epistemic probabilistic comparisons be established between metaphysical worldviews?
I have noticed that many discussions on this site compare worldviews—particularly theism versus naturalism—while implicitly assuming that the mathematical framework of probability theory can sensibly be applied to such comparisons. But is this assumption justified?
More formally, we would require a probabilistic function P(W), where W denotes a worldview. Additionally, there must exist a sample space S containing all possible worldviews, such that:

For P(W) to be practically useful and computable, we would also need a standardized representation of worldviews W that allows P to be implemented algorithmically, returning a probability value between 0 and 1.
However, this might be asking too much. A simpler approach could involve relative probabilities: instead of attempting to assign an absolute P(W) to each worldview, we could focus on comparing two specific worldviews W1 and W2. This could be achieved using a binary comparison function C(W1, W2), defined as:

Even if the absolute probabilities P(W) remain elusive, such a comparative framework might be more feasible—at least for certain classes of worldviews under specific conditions.
This leads to two key questions:

Optimistic case: Are there existing probabilistic methods to compare metaphysical worldviews? If so, could you point to references or examples of publications where such methods were developed and applied?

Pessimistic case: If no such methods exist, does this imply that claims like "worldview X is more probable than worldview Y" lack mathematical rigor and are, in fact, baseless? Without an objective probabilistic framework, do such assertions collapse into mere subjective opinion?



APPENDIX
Examples of questions assuming or entertaining the application of probability theory to metaphysics:

What is the probability of solipsism?
Is naturalism a subset of theism as a worldview? How does this affect their probabilities?
Does probability require a beginning? Can it apply to eternal things like god?
Can we assign probabilities to God and is the argument from improbability from Dawkins valid?


@Syed Looking forward to your answer :)

"Measure theory is a tool to model measures and thus is mind dependent, and thus cannot be objective"? "Quantum physics is a tool to model interactions between elementary particles and thus is mind dependent and thus cannot be objective"? "Logic is a tool to model valid inference and thus mind dependent and thus cannot be objective"?... Etc.

@mudskipper is that for me or for Syed?

@user80226 -- That's an implicit criticism of Syed's comment. It seems to me that Syed is using "objectivity" in an unusual way -- with some meaning that is unrelated to anything in science.

@Syed See above.

@mudskipper your analogy is fallacious. The principles of quantum physics would remain if we ceased to exist. If probability is a measure of uncertainty, and we stopped existing, there is no one to be uncertain of anything anymore. P.S. the questioner explicitly mentions epistemic probabilities. Epistemic implies mind dependence.

@Syed It has to be epistemic, because only one worldview is truly real, therefore that worldview has a real probability of 1 and every other worldview has a real probability of 0. So anything different from that would not reflect actual reality but our efforts to approximate it (i.e., epistemic).

@user80226 you are just further proving that “epistemic probablities” cannot be objective then which is what I said

@Syed I suppose they could be made objective, at least in principle, by standardizing an algorithm to estimate them.

We already have a framework for comparative probability statements, its called "likelihood ratio" and it avoids the need know the absolute probability of an event.

There is nothing within probability theory that states that it can be applied in certain contexts and not in others. Probability is a tool to model uncertainty in one’s head, and anything that is fundamentally mind dependent cannot arguably be objective.
In cases where it seems “objective”, such as in games of chance, it is purely due to convenience and practicality. After all, what sense would it make to assign the outcome of 1 on a dice any other probability than 1/6?
The real question then is not of objectivity but rather practicality. In the cases of worldviews, we don’t have historical repeated classes of an event as we do with dice, and thus it is hard to come up with probabilities that everyone would agree on, much less even make sense of. It is not as if we can roll a dice with one outcome being “theism” and another “naturalism” and then see how often they roll up for each.
However, this does not mean that we cannot roughly talk about the relative plausibility of worldviews. We do this already when making decisions between different options without making reference to any numbers or probabilities.

EDIT:
To answer your two questions, on the optimistic side of things, I am not aware of any probabilistic models that deal with metaphysics. The reason for this likely is due to models like this being untestable due to there being no historical data to test our probabilities with.
On the “pessimistic side”, you seem to be making a false dichotomy between having a probabilistic model and it being baseless to talk about a certain worldview being more probable than another. For example, one can use the epistemic virtues of simplicity or explanatory power to argue that theory A is more “probable” or “plausible” than theory B which doesn’t translate to an “objective” probabilistic model but also is more than just “subjective opinion”.

"this does not mean that we cannot roughly talk about the relative plausibility of worldviews" - Sure, we can talk about whatever we want. That doesn't mean that those words necessarily have to make any objective sense. The concept of "word salad" exists for a reason.

@user80226 When comparing the relative merits of a theory, why does it matter that an objective probabilistic figure isn’t attached to each theory?

In order to ask Why X? you need show first that X exists.

Can you please edit your answer in order to explicitly address the two sub-questions asked in my question (optimistic and pessimistic cases)?

@user80226 sure
